# How can I use crontab to apt update and apt upgrade (as the sudo user) using Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: cron

I want to run `apt update` and `apt upgrade` once per day.

I `sudo crontab -e` and put: `00 13 * * * apt update && apt upgrade` My impression is that these command will run (as sudo user) at 13:00 every day.

However, having tried this, when I run `sudo apt list --upgradable` I get:

```
glib-networking/bionic-updates,bionic-security 2.56.0-1ubuntu0.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.56.0-1]
glib-networking-common/bionic-updates,bionic-updates,bionic-security,bionic-security 2.56.0-1ubuntu0.1 all [upgradable from: 2.56.0-1]
glib-networking-services/bionic-updates,bionic-security 2.56.0-1ubuntu0.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.56.0-1]
libseccomp2/bionic-updates,bionic-security 2.4.3-1ubuntu3.18.04.2 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.4.1-0ubuntu0.18.04.2]
libxau-dev/bionic-updates 1:1.0.8-1ubuntu1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1:1.0.8-1]
libxau6/bionic-updates 1:1.0.8-1ubuntu1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1:1.0.8-1]
```

Which suggests that the updating / upgrading has not happened. So what am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Does [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1015522/8505596) help you? Furthermore, you could use `root`'s crontab (in root, run `crontab -e` and run it under that context). I'm sure it's frowned upon, but it *should* work.

Comment: Seems that you are inventing `unattended-upgrades` [service](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/all/unattended-upgrades/filelist) or `apt-daily` [tasks](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&arch=any&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=apt-daily) , it would be easer to configure them neither invent new unique bicycle.

Comment: @DankyNanky `sudo crontab -e` **does** use root's crontab - perhaps you are thinking of the system-wide crontab file `/etc/crontab`?

Comment: @steeldriver - Correct - ignore my ramblings, I'll leave my comment with an update.

Comment: `apt upgrade` requires user input. You forgot the `-y` flag. If you use non-Ubuntu sources, this method is not recommended - a version conflict will error the upgrade every time without notifying you.

Comment: I am using the root's crontab; I also have a non-root crontab. I thought that using the sudo crontab meant I didn't need to use a password. I'm still not sure how to resolve this issue.

Comment: @user535733 has given you the answer. Your crontab entry should be 00 13 * * * apt update && apt upgrade -y. Without that -y the job fails because the is no user to enter y to proceed.

Comment: @user535733 Care to post as an answer so we can close this question?

Comment: @PonJar You could probably post as an answer as well since you were the first to give the full command.

Comment: @LyndonGingerich anyone (including you) can post the answer.

Comment: @user535733 Noted. I was thinking to be courteous and not steal rep from those who do the work.

Comment: @LyndonGingerich thanks for being thoughtful!

Answer (score 3):

`apt upgrade` is interactive: It requires the user to review and approve changes.

It can work non-interactively (like in a script) with the `-y` flag.

- **Warning**: `-y` is not recommended for most daily use. It disables an important protection from human folly. A version conflict, common when using non-Ubuntu sources, will error the upgrade every time **without** notifying you.

So if using a crontab, `00 13 * * * apt update && apt upgrade -y` would be be needed.

- Keep in mind that a stock Ubuntu system ALREADY checks for deb and snap updates daily, and automatically downloads Main security updates (deb) and updated snap applications. This crontab needlessly duplicates some of those existing services.